# apt-get update can not connect

Tags: ubuntu, iptables, kvm-virtualization, apt, libvirt

i run a dedicated ubuntu 10.04 server.

i use kvm/libvirt/virsh to run a virtual machine that's also ubuntu 10.04.

i bridged the network (1 of 2 IPs is routed via NAT to the LAN, where my VM (192.168.1.111) picks it up.

i can locally connect to the vm via ssh from the vm i can ping any site outside my network.

i routed port 80 (and others) through using iptables and i can connect from the outside to my apache on the vm .

yet, apt is not working at all, which kills me because i can't install anything...

```
$ apt-get update
```

leads to a series of errors like this:

```
W: Failed to fetch http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/lucid-backports/multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages.gz  Unable to connect to de.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 141.30.13.30 80]
```

i can ping the domain and ip from the terminal without a problem.

i can resolveip the domain without a problem.

i tried all /etc/apt/sources.list variations i found on the net. the one working from my dedicated machine, the default list, several hand-compiled lists. the result is always the same: unable to connect

I think it is some kind of a routing problem, but i am really puzzled, because i seem to have full network access from the vm. As the packages are not installed i can't wget or ftp from the vm terminal (and i can't compile them as no gcc is installed - i wanted to do all that using apt ;) ). oh, aptitude is the same of course...

HELP!

P.S. here are my iptables settings:

```
iptables -t nat -L -v
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 86 packets, 14254 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 DNAT       tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:https to:192.168.1.111:443
    0     0 DNAT       tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:ftp to:192.168.1.111:21
   13   780 DNAT       tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:www to:192.168.1.111:80

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 31 packets, 2236 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 MASQUERADE  tcp  --  any    any     192.168.1.0/24      !192.168.1.0/24      masq ports: 1024-65535
    1    76 MASQUERADE  udp  --  any    any     192.168.1.0/24      !192.168.1.0/24      masq ports: 1024-65535
    1    84 MASQUERADE  all  --  any    any     192.168.1.0/24      !192.168.1.0/24

iptables -L -v
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 1699 packets, 354K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
   18  1179 ACCEPT     udp  --  virbr0 any     anywhere             anywhere            udp dpt:domain
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  virbr0 any     anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:domain
    2   656 ACCEPT     udp  --  virbr0 any     anywhere             anywhere            udp dpt:bootps
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  virbr0 any     anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:bootps

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
 2448 3146K ACCEPT     all  --  any    any     anywhere             192.168.1.0/24      state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  any    virbr0  anywhere             192.168.1.0/24      state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
 1448 79657 ACCEPT     all  --  virbr0 any     192.168.1.0/24       anywhere
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  virbr0 virbr0  anywhere             anywhere
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  any    virbr0  anywhere             anywhere            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  virbr0 any     anywhere             anywhere            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
```

@g-bach

okay, below are the filter rules (iptables -L -v -t filter).

about the architecture: host with 2 ips mapped to eth0 and eth1.
eth1 is bridget for libvirt. and should route/masq to different VMs (usually we have no overlapping ports open for the VMs - at least not below 1024).

after playing around a bit more I can specify the problem a bit better:

it's the firewall (iptables) rules. I obviously don't get how to setup iptables (never did that before). 
When I played around with them wildly, I got different things to work, others not (connections to ubuntu servers worked, no incoming connections worked anymore, etc.).

Hence, you were right and the bridge etc is okay. About the pinging and connecting from the VM to the outside: it's not working with wget and ssh/telnet . there is an initial connection, but I then no data is sent (i routed 20, 21 and 22 through) . also - e.g. i can install apache and wordpress in the VM and connect to it from the outside, but then wordpress can't establish a ftp connection to fetch updates etc.

iptables -L -v -t filter

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 19574 packets, 7015K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
   27  1757 ACCEPT     udp  --  virbr0 any     anywhere             anywhere            udp dpt:domain
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  virbr0 any     anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:domain
   43 14104 ACCEPT     udp  --  virbr0 any     anywhere             anywhere            udp dpt:bootps
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  virbr0 any     anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:bootps

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
 1850  119K ACCEPT     all  --  any    any     anywhere             192.168.1.0/24      state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  any    virbr0  anywhere             192.168.1.0/24      state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
 1538  308K ACCEPT     all  --  virbr0 any     192.168.1.0/24       anywhere
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  virbr0 virbr0  anywhere             anywhere
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  any    virbr0  anywhere             anywhere            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  virbr0 any     anywhere             anywhere            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 5787 packets, 635K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

thanks for your efforts!

Comment: this is not bridging, this VM is behind a NAT, according to your decription. What is the VM's IP? Do you see any errors if you run tcpdump on the VM? what about tcpdump on the host? all during the apt command execution of course

Comment: sudo apt-get update ?

Answer (score 1):

Since you can ping sites from the VM, routing can't be the problem - at least I don't see how it could.
Could you maybe post the iptables for the filter-table? Maybe there's a problem with forwarding outgoing new connections over specific ports.

Just to make sure I understood correctly what topology you are using: you have a physical Ubuntu 10.04 server with two IPs, on that server you run a VM which has one interface that is bridged to one of the interfaces of the server? I think I got something wrong here, doesn't quite match up your description...

On another note, is it intentional INPUT and OUTPUT have their policies set to ACCEPT and additionally a bunch of rules that also jump to ACCEPT? I don't see how that could affect your problem, I'm just curious :P